# How to install Neo4j batch importer on Windows

Tags: neo4j, installation, batch-processing

I tried to create large database with Neo4j and it takes substantial time to create nodes and relationships (about 1 million each). I read that a good solution is to use the Neo4j batch importer but how do I install it ? I'm using Neo4j 2.1.4 on Windows 7. Thank you for your help. Sam

Comment: In general LOAD CSV can also deal with 1M lines, read my blog post for some tips on making it fast. http://jexp.de/blog/2014/10/load-cvs-with-success/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to use batch import is via https://github.com/jexp/batch-import. With that you don't have to write custom code. Instead you provide two csv files, one for nodes and one for relationship and run the import via maven.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. Do you think this version of the batch is a good one ? It seems to be an update to use the batch importer without maven https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/superfast-batch-importer

Comment: But how to run the .sh file as explained in on the website ?

Comment: superfast batch importer is a newer development. The github repo contains a `import.bat` as well. sh files are for unices.

Comment: Ok but when I run the .bat file it creates a file called batch.properties and it closes the command prompt. What do I have to do to enter the files names of the CSV that I have ?

Comment: Ok I'm a fool I guess I juste have to launch it from the command prompt :-)